# How do I get useful diagnostics from boto?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

How can I get useful diagnostics out of boto?  All I ever seem to get is the infuriatingly useless "400 Bad Request".  I recognize that boto is just passing along what the underlying API makes available, but surely there's some way to get something more useful than "Bad Request".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mongo_pulldown.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "./mongo_pulldown.py", line 24, in main
    print "snap = %r" % snap
  File "./mongo_pulldown.py", line 149, in __exit__
    self.connection.delete_volume(self.volume.id)
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 1507, in delete_volume
    return self.get_status('DeleteVolume', params, verb='POST')
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 985, in get_status
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: `import boto;    boto.set_stream_logger('boto')` will print json results including any errors experienced to the console.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't have much luck with putting the debug setting in the config file, but the call to ec2.connect_to_region() takes a debug parameter, with the same values as in j0nes' answer.

```
ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1", debug=2)
```

Everything that connection object sends/receives will get dumped to stdout.

Answer (score 8):

You can [configure the boto.cfg](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#boto) file to be more verbose:

```
[Boto]
debug = 2
```

> debug:     Controls the level of debug messages that will be printed by
>   the boto library. The following values are defined:
>
> ```
> 0 - no debug messages are printed
> 1 - basic debug messages from boto are printed
> 2 - all boto debugging messages plus request/response messages from httplib
> ```

Comment: That doesn't give any more information.  The problem is that the HTTP response that comes back just has "400 Bad Request" in the body.  What I really need is some way to get the server to give more information about what went wrong.

Comment: From the code, it looks like one can turn this info on on a per-connection basis.  Example?